# Does the equation $u_{xx}-u=0$ with inicial data have unique solution?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the exercise $1.45$ of *Fourier Analysis and Partial Differential Equations (Rafael Iorio)*, which says

> Consider the following problem: $$\begin{cases} \partial^2_xu(x,y)-u(x,y)=0 & \text{for all }(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\\u(0,y) = f(y) & \text{for all }y\in\mathbb{R}\\\partial_xu(0,y) = g(y) & \text{for all }y\in\mathbb{R} \end{cases}$$ where $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $f,g\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$. Find a solution of the above problem and prove that it is the only solution.

Since the PDE does not involve partial derivatives respect to $y$, I solved it as the ODE $u''(x)-u(x)=0$ by considering the constant terms in the solution as functions of $y$, and then I used the inicial data to get the solution $$u(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}[f(y)+g(y)]e^x+\frac{1}{2}[f(y)-g(y)]e^{-x}.$$  In order to prove the uniqueness of the solution, I guess that I should consider that $u$ and $v$ are solutions of the PDE, and then prove that $w=u-v\equiv 0$. In this case, $w$ holds the equation $w_{xx}(x,y)-w(x,y)=0$ with $w(0,y)=0=w_x(0,y)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're essentially done: the same formula you found with $w$ playing the role of $u$ says that $$w(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(0 + 0){\rm e}^{x} + \frac{1}{2}(0-0){\rm e}^{-x} = 0,$$since $w(0,y) =0$ and $w_x(0,y) = 0$. In other words, your solution for $u$ is manifestly unique: you have found a concrete formula and it couldn't be anything else.

Comment: I don't get it. I know that I am using a method to find a solution of the PDE, but it does not mean that it's the only possible solution. I think your idea is circular, because you are using that the solution obtained with this approach is the only one.

Comment: This is a logic problem, not a PDE problem: you work shows that *if* $u$ is a solution, *then* $u$ must be given by that formula. How to justify it? Do what you did.

Comment: I understand your point, but what I don't like is the fact that I used the method of second order ODE to make the first step, so I should prove that with that method we get the only possible solution to the analogous problem of second order PDE, and it seems to be hard.